# how to simulate a mouse click on a background application in c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# forms application and I want to simulate a mouse click of a button of background application without having to bring the program into focus. This is for an email spammer that I have been working on and I need to bring up a new email.

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't have any code to share, I'll point you to [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are a few examples of its implementation.